# Send data to Delphi server

Tags: html, delphi, indy

I'm making a Delphi XE5 VCL Forms Application with a `TIdHTTPServer` on the main form and a `CommandGet` of the `IdHTTPServer` procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var pageContent: TStringList;
begin
if pos('&command=add', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
   begin
      pageContent:= TStringList.Create;
      try
         pageContent.Add('<html>');
         pageContent.Add('<head>');
         pageContent.Add('<title>Profile</title>');
         pageContent.Add('</head>');
         pageContent.Add('<body>');
         pageContent.Add('<input id="subjects" type="text"/>');
         pageContent.Add('<input id="Add" type="button" onclick="sendData()"/>');
         pageContent.Add('</body>');
         pageContent.Add('</html>');
         AResponseInfo.ContentText := pageContent.Text;
      finally
         pageContent.Free;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

My question is how the user input is send to the server when the user clicks the button 'Add'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this HTML, the client (web browser) will not send any data because there is no HTML form element present.

Comment: I'm making a javascript function and added onclick action on the button 'Add'. The function contains this line: xmlhttp.open('POST',  document.URL + '&command=add' + '&confirm=', true); and I add another case in CommandGet procedure. I also add a method that processes the input data but I haven't finished it yet